# Given one exact measurement, how can I use it to measure the rest?

Tags: vector, 3d, cs5, measurement

I'm asking **how to use a given measurement to create a custom scale that I can use to accurately measure the rest.**

I have a vector file that looks like:

[image: Car Wireframe]

I wish to measure parts of the car, to build a 3D model.

How can I use the single measurement provided to measure the rest?

Which of the Adobe CS5 programs can I use for this, and what tool should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with Photoshop using the Ruler Tool and a [Custom Measurement Scale](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WS7901119A-3EE7-4806-B5AF-1A6D58827A81a.html#WS251DEEC3-5CA0-4bdf-9C63-9E7C28AF295Da).

Using your provided image as an example, do the following:

1. Activate the **Ruler Tool** (you may have to click and hold the eyedropper tool)
2. Check the **Use Measurement Scale** tickbox on the top toolbar
3. Measure the width of the provided scale (541 pixels)
4. Go to **Analysis** → **Set Measurement Scale** → ***Custom...***
5. Enter the known values and hit OK

[image: custom measurement scale]

The ruler measurements will now use your custom scale. For instance, it looks like the tires are 752mm tall

[image: tire height]

To revert back to pixel measurements, you can untick "Use Measurement Scale"

Comment: @Dominic I wish the same feature was available in AI, but I don't know of any way to do so (although I'd love to be proven wrong). Perhaps with a script? Lucky for you that you'll need to bring them into PS anyway, so it doesn't matter in your case!